# Using the if statement and for loop to write a program that generates N random numbers (and more)

Tags: matlab, random, modulo

The question:

Write a matlab program that

i) generates N<=20 random numbers in the interval [a,b], where *N, a, b* are entered via keyboard

My attempt:

```
a = input ('a=')
b = input ('b=')
N = input ('N=')

 for N = (1:N)
     r = rand([a,b],[1,N])
 end
```

doesn't seem to work. The following error messages appear

"??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

What am I doing wrong?

ii) write the numbers to a vector/array *x*

NO idea how to do this?
Is it simply a matter of putting r = x?

iii) write all the numbers divisible by *k* to the screen, *k* is entered via the keyboard.

My attempt:

```
k = input ('k=')
t = mod(x,k);

 for x = i:N
  if mod(x,k) == 0
  disp t
  end
 end
```

Am I anywhere near correct?

[I've never used stack-overflow before- having trouble formatting things appropriately] Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get N random numbers in range [a, b]:

```
a = input('a=');
b = input('b=');
N = input('N=');

% For floating point:
r1 = a + (b-a)*rand(1, N);
% For integers:
r2 = round(a + (b-a)*rand(1, N));
```

As you can see, r1 and r2 are already in vector form, so:

```
x = r1;
% or
x = r2;
```

For the last part (this will print duplicates as well):

```
k = input('k=');
divs_found = find(mod(r, k) == 0);
disp(r(divs_found));
```

Comment: I wonder if I'm using an outdated version of Matlab (R2007b) because it keeps saying "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" when I enter values into the inputs.

Comment: This is weird. I'm using 2008b and get no errors but I don't think "input" works differently in 2007b. Maybe you have defined a function or matrix named "input"?

Comment: When I run this program it says "the index exceeds matrix dimensions"...why?

Comment: Can you post the whole error exactly? Are you absolutely sure you haven't define any function/variable named "input"(eg. "input = 5;")? I can't see why this type of error could occur on input.